# Determine the effect of a binary variable?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

Consider that a site A has ten thousand web pages. For each of the web pages, the server keeps the number of people visited each of those pages (plus some additional characteristics, such as popularity in the form of upvote and downvote count). Each webpage also has a creation date. Now,  consider that 1000 of those web pages are moved to site B after t time from their creation date (t can be different for different web pages). I have collected the number of people visit those moved web pages between t and t+x time.

My goal is to evaluate the following hypothesis: moving the question from site A to site B increases the number of people visit those web pages.

What is the proper way or technique to evaluate this hypothesis? Can I use a regression model here? I have some experience of using a regression model and I can include the movement event as a variable (such as 0 or 1) in the model. However, I am not sure how to model this particular situation.

The closest question I found is this one: [How to determine if a (binary) variable has a statistically significant effect on a response variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191456/how-to-determine-if-a-binary-variable-has-a-statistically-significant-effect-o)
But, unfortunately, the current answer appears to be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the difference between each sample in condition A and B, i.e. x_i = b_i - a_i and then perform a t-test or Wilcoxon test to check whether mean difference is significantly different from 0.

If you're interested in whether B leads to more visits than A  on average, you can do a one-sided test with H0: u <= 0.

However, you should be careful here since there may be other things to consider in your case, e.g. are the visits counted in the same time period for each sample? Does the fact that a web-page is available on A before B reduce visits in B? All of this could bias the outcome of your analyis.